# How to compute the width/diameter of a blood vessel with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a project which involves an objective of computing the with/diameter of a blood vessel. In cases involving stenosis, the vessels will not have equal width/diameter throughout, thus possibly a partition of the vessel has to be done and widths for each partition will be computed separately.

However, I am stuck at the step on how the width/diameter can be computed. For example, consider the vessel (circled in red) below:

[image]

which I obtained from [How to segment blood vessels python opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403205/how-to-segment-blood-vessels-python-opencv) initially.

Suppose that I am able to remove all unimportant vessels leaving only the vessel marked red above, are there actually standard procedures which I can proceed with to compute the width/diameter of the vessel of interest? For example, the ideal output for the above vessel should be the maximum width/diameter and the width/diameter for each partition of the vessel.

I have tried looking up online literature and resources, but the closest I got was to obtain the plot above, without computation of vessel width/diameter.

Some insights and directions will be of great help as I am at a loss right now..

Comment: So you want to find two opposite points on the vessel edge, that will give you the width?

Comment: @danishansari Yes that is correct.

Comment: Assuming you can remove other vessels and keep only one encircled in red, You can find the contour, which will give points on edges on the vessel, I think the shape of the vessel can be random, so choose contour of smaller sizes and find the axis fit to the data using PCA, choose a point on the contour and using angle from PCA you can find the opposite point on the contour. Repeat this for all segments of contour them may be you can choose to take average or median of the values you get.

Comment: @danishansari Thanks for your feedback and recommendations. That seems like a good place to start. Are there any existing libraries to perform the above computations?

Comment: OpenCV is there.